“ 'Task' has no accessible initializers” issue for SwiftUI
How can I use:
struct TestView: View {
    @StateObject private var housesListVM = HousesListViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .onAppear {
                Task {
                    await housesListVM.fetchAll()
                }
            }
    }
}


Function:
@MainActor
func fetchAll() async {
    self.networking = true

    let params: Parameters = ["Page": 1,
                              "Take": 100,
                              "NeedTotalCount": false,
                              "SortBy": "",
                              "SortAscending": true,
                              "FirstHomeId": "\(self.selectedFirstHome)"]

    let endpoint = HouseEndpoint.paginate(params: params)

    do {
        
        let result: PaginationBase<[House]> = try await APIAgentTest.shared.runRequest(endPoint: endpoint)

        self.all = result.result ?? []
        self.filtered = result.result ?? []
        self.listIsFetched = true
    } catch let error as ErrorResponse {
        
        print("Error: \(error.errorMessage)")
        self.all = []
        self.filtered = []
    } catch {
        print("Unexpected Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        self.all = []
        self.filtered = []
    }

    self.networking = false
}


Requirements:
Apple Swift version 6.0.3
Target: arm64-apple-macosx15.0
According to the information I have given above, I am trying to use this way in Task usage, but I get an error in a way I do not understand. I am providing everything requested.
What do I need to do?
I am converting the closure type network request functions to async/await structure to improve them, but I am stuck.

Do not post pictures of code. It's impossible to see and can't be searched, copied, or tested.

Thanks for your feedback, ı have fixed that.

This code snippet is insufficient to manifest the problem. Putting it (or a simplified version) into a blank project and you will not experience this problem. I wonder if you have defined your own Task type somewhere (or given the warning message, maybe one of your imports). You can confirm this thesis by temporarily replacing Task {…} with _Concurrency.Task {…} and see if that silences the error. If so, you might be able to command-click on Task to take you to the definition. Or create copy of your project and remove third-party packages one by one until you identify the culprit.

In general, in SwiftUI, I agree with malhal that one would use the .task view modifier (though I disagree that it necessarily means replacing state objects; that’s a completely separate topic, and entirely a matter of opinion). So, rather than introducing unstructured concurrency with Task {…} in .onAppear {…}, we would generally use .task {…}. Not only is it simpler, but you enjoy automatic cancellation when the view is dismissed. But you might want to identify the source of the discrepancy, regardless.

FWIW, I think the suggested duplicate is a related, but different, problem.

You can use .task for async/await it is designed to replace @StateObject, just do:
.task{ // runs on appear 
   items = await fetcher.fetchItems
}

Put your fetcher struct that contains the async func in the Environment if you would like to mock it for previews.
